# Rundeck Powershell pass options to script

Tags: powershell, rundeck

My question is how do I pass options/ parameter into a PowerShell  script? Could not find it on the docs or any other good post about it. I know it's possible because I saw it in a video from the rundeck YouTube channel.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and amend the question, the we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using inline script just add `@option.youroption@`, make sure to [fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlBIZ.jpg) the right params to execute in your windows box. I leave a couple of examples, take a look:

Job definition (inline PowerShell script):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt1' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>700b58f6-9bae-4d97-b97d-dd4c7efba9ca</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobWINRM</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>name: windows</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "hi"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.ps1</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[Write-Host "@option.opt1@"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>powershell.exe</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>700b58f6-9bae-4d97-b97d-dd4c7efba9ca</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Using "external script" [passing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xPur.jpg) some parameter in "Arguments" textbox.

Powershell script:

```powershell
### hello.ps1 ###
Param($Variable1 = "Hello", $Variable2 = "World")
"$Variable1 $Variable2"
```

Rundeck Job definition:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt1' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>854a8639-ad98-4520-b446-359ec2eaf531</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobWINRMEXT</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>name: windows</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "hi"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.ps1</fileExtension>
        <scriptargs>"${option.opt1}"</scriptargs>
        <scriptfile>/home/user/scripts/hello.ps1</scriptfile>
        <scriptinterpreter>powershell.exe</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>854a8639-ad98-4520-b446-359ec2eaf531</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```